# Question About Dual Vector Spaces and the Adjoint Map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding some things about this problem:

> Suppose that $U \subset V$ is a subspace. Let $I : U \rightarrow V$ be the inclusion map. The adjoint map $I^* : V^* \rightarrow U^*$ has a kernel: $$U^{\bot} := \mathrm{ ker}\; I^* \subset V^*$$ Show that $U^* \cong V^*/U^{\bot}$ ($U$ dual is isomorphic to $V$ dual mod $U^{\bot}$) by showing that elements of $V^*/U^{\bot}$ act as linear functionals $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Conclude from this that subspaces of $V$ are in one-to-one correspondence with quotients of $V^*$ and vice-versa.

We know that if $\eta$ is in the kernel of $I^*$, then $I^*\eta = 0 \in U^*$, so then $\forall u \in U, (I^*\eta)u = 0 = \eta(Iu) = \eta(u)$. And then $\{ \eta : U \subset \mathrm{ker} \;\eta\} = U^{\bot}$.

I don't understand how $U$ perp is a set of functionals. Isn't U perp just an ordinary vector space? Or are we using a notion of U perp that is different from the conventional usage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the *annihilator* $U^\perp$ of $U$ is defined as the kernel of $I^\ast : V^\ast \to U^\ast$, and hence, in particular, is a subspace of $V^\ast$, making it a set of functionals on $V$.

Now, what you're thinking of is the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $V$, in the case that $V$ is an inner product space; the point is that the annihilator $U^\perp \subset V^\ast$ is the generalisation of the orthogonal complement $U^\perp \subset V$ in the absence of an inner product on $V$. So, in the finite dimensional case, for simplicity, an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ defines an isomorphism $R : V \to V^\ast$, conjugate-linear if you're working over $\mathbb{C}$, by $v \mapsto \langle v,\cdot \rangle$. You can then check that $R$ restricts to an isomorphism
$$
 \text{orthogonal complement of $U$ in $V$} \to \text{annihilator of $U$ in $V^\ast$}.
$$

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense. Thank you. Just to be sure, the orthogonal complement of $U$ is an ordinary vector space and the annihilator of $U$ in $V$ is a dual space, correct?

Comment: The orthogonal complement is a subspace of the original vector space $V$, whilst the annihilator is a subspace of the dual space $V^\ast$.